# How to handle null values in json response in Go using json.NewDecoder

Tags: json, api, go

This is my struct:

```
type Media struct {
    MediaID   string `json:"media_id"`
    MediaType float64    `json:"media_type"`
    ViewCount float64    `json:"view_count"`
}
```

I'm writing an API to serve some media files and I'm using json.NewDecoder to decode and work with the response. I populate my struct like this way:

```
media := Media{
                MediaID:   media["media_id"].(string),
                MediaType: media["media_type"].(float64),
                ViewCount: media["view_count"].(float64),
}
```

It works fine in many situations but the problem is that sometimes *view_count* is null and it gives me this error:

**interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not float64**

I really appreciate any comments!

This is all the code before trying to extract response fields:

```
var (
    r  map[string]interface{}
)

var buf bytes.Buffer

query := map[string]interface{}{
    "query": map[string]interface{}{
        "match": map[string]interface{}{
            "content": params["q"],
        },
    },
}

if err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(query); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error encoding query: %s", err)
}

res, err = es.Search(
    es.Search.WithContext(context.Background()),
    es.Search.WithIndex("myindex"),
    es.Search.WithBody(&buf),
    es.Search.WithTrackTotalHits(true),
    es.Search.WithPretty(),
)

if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&r); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error parsing the response body: %s", err)
}
```

Comment: Are you decoding the JSON to the `media`?   If so, why not decode directly to the struct? To answer the question, use a two-value type assertion and handle the false value.

Comment: I'm decoding the response to map[string]interface{}. Then I try to populate Media struct like this. Is there any get(value or None) solution like in python??

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not decode directly to the struct?

Comment: This is a part of an elasticsearch response. I don't need all the fields just a part of it. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not necessary to declare a struct field for every key in the JSON object. It might be helpful to show some more of the code. If the JSON is decoded to map[string]interface{} and you have no control over that, then this question is not about type assertions and not JSON.

Comment: @MuffinTop I've added some of my codes. I have control over how to decode JSON. actually I'm new to Go. I taught this is the right way to do this. What is your suggestion?

Comment: Decode to the struct directly: `var media Media; if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&media); err != nil { /* handle error */}`

Answer (score 1):

If you have nil for some fields, solution is POINTER!

this code is enough if you use binding

```
type Media struct {
    MediaID   string `json:"media_id"`
    MediaType float64    `json:"media_type"`
    ViewCount *float64    `json:"view_count"`
}
```

but if you wanna assign it field by field (which is not a good idea) before assigning you should check if media["view_count"] is exist or not

```
var viewCount float64
tmpViewCount, ok := madia["view_count"]
if ok {
   viewCount = tmpViewCount.(float64)
}

media := Media{
   MediaID:   media["media_id"].(string),
   MediaType: media["media_type"].(float64),
   ViewCount: viewCount,
}
```

Comment: When I use your method it gives me this error: 
interface conversion: interface {} is float64, not *float64

Comment: my method is two different part, erase * from float64.

Comment: I'm looking for something like your first method but it doesn't work and gives me the above error. your second solution works fine.

Comment: @Neo if you working with JSON you can try json.Unmarshal https://ednsquare.com/story/marshal-and-unmarshal-of-struct-to-json-in-golang------CG5PTJ

Comment: I found out that for stream application like in my case, it's better to use NewDecoder rather than Unmarshal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217264/discussion-between-diako-amir-and-neo).

Answer (score 1):

The numeric fields in `Media` should probably be integer values instead of floating point values:

```
type Media struct {
    MediaID   string `json:"media_id"`
    MediaType int    `json:"media_type"`
    ViewCount int    `json:"view_count"`
}
```

Use pointers if the numeric fields if the JSON document uses `null` for these values. Hopefully that's not the case because the application must write a bit of extra code to deference the pointers.

```
type Media struct {
    MediaID   string `json:"media_id"`
    MediaType *int    `json:"media_type"`
    ViewCount *int    `json:"view_count"`
}
```

Either way, decode directly to  `Media` as suggested in the question's commentary:

```
var media Media
if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&media); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error parsing the response body: %s", err)
}
```